# How to process audio from microphone of WP7 immediately?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, microphone

I am looking for way to process audio from microphone immediately (add some effect and so on). I checked API of microphone in WP7 and didn't find there way for this (I can do it only by portions after)

Could anybody suggest me way to access audio immediately after it sounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to process it through the standard microphone routines anyway, so even if you plan on implementing an "as-you-go" sound changer, you would still need to access the buffer, perform modifications, and then replay. Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442302%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: So as I get I shout set small interval for simulation of XNA loop? Which value is suitable?

Comment: From 100 to one second with 10 step )